# Angular-moment - cannot read property 'utc' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I am trying to use angular-moment's directive `am-time-go` but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'utc' of undefined
```

I use it in a simple controller like this (in jade):

```
    span(am-time-ago="myItem.date")
```

And my dates work fine, their format is the following:

```
2014-10-29T23:31:23Z
```

I have also tried configuring my module:

```
myApp.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
    preprocess: 'utc',
    timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'
});
```

But nothing works. Where does this problem stem from?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, since v2.4 moment is not a global object any more, which resulted in 'undefined' everytime angular-moment made a reference to moment.

I switch to v.2.3.1, it works like a charm now

Comment: Are you using require.js or similar? see https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/36

Answer (score 13):

Please see working sample below. Make sure that you've got reference to all scripts and they are in proper order

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularMoment']);

app.constant('angularMomentConfig', {
  preprocess: 'utc',
  timezone: 'Europe/Berlin'
});

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myItem = {
    date: "2014-10-29T23:31:23Z"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/0.8.2/angular-moment.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">


    <span am-time-ago="myItem.date"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue until I moved the moment.js script tag before the angular-moment.js script tag. Try putting your script tags in this order...

```
<script src="/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It clearly seems to be an issue of new `momentjs`, in which `moment` is not available as a global variable.

For those working with `nwjs`, this [comment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/194#issuecomment-154767249) in issue [#194](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment/issues/194) worked for me.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['angularMoment']);
var moment_mod = require('moment');
app.constant('moment', moment_mod);
```

I also tried the beta.4 version of `angular-moment`(in my nwjs app) which passes a warning to use npm module of `moment` (so that a global moment object is available from the start).

Answer (score 0):

For those working with `nwjs`, I got all my modules working with this :

`if (typeof nw !== "undefined" && nw !== null) {
    console.log('NW detected, remove global !');
    window.node_global = global;
    window.global = void 0;
}`